# Only the first "if function" derives latest version of a .js page (wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The following is used to load the latest version of a .js page onto a wordpress page. The first set (assets1) works fine. However, the second function fails to load the latest version of the js page, only the original upload. I would like both functions to derive the latest version of the .js page, what do I need to change to do this?

```
function load_js_assets1() {
    if( is_page( 'Example Page 1' ) ) {
        $datetime = new DateTime('now');
        $revision = $datetime->format("YmdHis"); 
        wp_enqueue_script('example1.js?'.$revision, 'http://website.com/example1.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets1');
function load_js_assets2() {
    if( is_page( 'Example Page 2' ) ) {
        $datetime = new DateTime('now');
        $revision = $datetime->format("YmdHis"); 
        wp_enqueue_script('example2.js'.$revision, 'http://website.com/example2.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things.

1. You can add the version/revision to the enqueue hook itself, so you don't have to worry about concatenating the version to the filename and accidentally excluding characters like '?'.  The hook does that for you.
2. You are missing the add_action on the second function.
3. You should just combine the two if statements into the same function.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
function load_js_assets() {

    // Declare your revision variables once

    $datetime = new DateTime('now');
    $revision = $datetime->format("YmdHis"); 

    // Test against first statement.  If true enqueue the first script

    if( is_page( 'Example Page 1' ) ) {  
        wp_enqueue_script('example1.js', 'http://website.com/example1.js', array('jquery'), $revision, false);
    }

    // Test against second statement.  If true enqueue the second script

    if( is_page( 'Example Page 2' ) ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script('example2.js', 'http://website.com/example2.js', array('jquery'), $revision, false);
    }

    // Do more if needed...

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second `add_action` which can be the reason why the second script is not loading correctly. Try this code, which uses two functions and `add_action` if you are on the pages you want them to be used:

```
function load_js_assets1() {
   $datetime = new DateTime('now');
   $revision = $datetime->format("YmdHis"); 
   wp_enqueue_script('example1.js?'.$revision, 'http://website.com/example1.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
}

function load_js_assets2() {
   $datetime = new DateTime('now');
   $revision = $datetime->format("YmdHis"); 
   wp_enqueue_script('example2.js'.$revision, 'http://website.com/example2.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
}

if( is_page( 'Example Page 1' ) ) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets1');
}

if( is_page( 'Example Page 2' ) ) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets2');
}
```